# How to update a python application over internet?

Tags: python, pyqt4, updates

I've been building a Python 2.7 app with a gui made in PyQt4. For some time I was wondering how can I integrate an update service for my app. I use 2 versions, one build for linux using cx_freeze and the other one for windows using cx_freeze too.

I looked on internet but I didn't had much luck. All I managed to do is to check the current version and the new version on my server, but I want to start downloading the new files and replace the old ones.

Comment: You can check out [esky](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky)